# Issues using preg_match_all results with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I'm using preg_mat to replace if statements in a template. I've been trying to get at the matches from preg_match_all and get the results from the match and use preg_replace on that, but I'm getting offset errors.

Any assistance on the syntax would be greatly appreciated. Also curious if there is a better way to go about this.

Code sample:

```
public function output() {

$output = file_get_contents($this->file);

foreach ($this->values as $key => $value) {
    $tagToReplace = "[@$key]";
    $output = str_replace($tagToReplace, $value, $output);

    $dynamic = preg_quote($key);
    $pattern = '%\[if @'.$dynamic.'\](.*?)\[/if\]%'; // produces: %\[if @username\](.*?)\[/if\]%

    if ($value == '') {
    $output = preg_replace($pattern, "", $output);  
    } else {
    preg_match_all($pattern, $output, $if_match);
    $output = preg_replace("%\[if @".$dynamic."\]%", "", $if_match[0][0]);
    $output = preg_replace("%\[/if]%", "", $if_match[0][0]);        
    }
```

Template except:

```
    [if @username] <p>A statement goes here and this is [@username]</p> [/if]
    [if @sample] <p>Another statement goes here</p> [/if]
```

Controller excerpt:

```
$layout->set("username", "My Name");
$layout->set("sample", "");
```

Comment: At this point you should consider just using a working templating engine. (Your previous preg_replace_callback approach wasn't clever, but more senseful than this step-wise string mangling.)

Comment: Thanks -- that's what I was about to try next. It's a very small template engine for a resume. I do know Smarty well enough, but I'm partially doing this to as a learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Using a callback and then running preg_replace on the $matches solved the problem:

```
public function output() {

$output = file_get_contents($this->file);

foreach ($this->values as $key => $value) {
    $tagToReplace = "[@$key]";
    $output = str_replace($tagToReplace, $value, $output);

    $dynamic = preg_quote($key);
    $pattern = '%\[if @'.$dynamic.'\](.*?)\[/if\]%'; // produces: %\[if @username\](.*?)\[/if\]%

    if ($value == '') {
    $output = preg_replace($pattern, "", $output);  
    } else {
    $callback = new MyCallback($key, $value);
    $output = preg_replace_callback($pattern, array($callback, 'callback'), $output);
    }

}

return $output;
}


}

class MyCallback {
private $key;
private $value;

function __construct($key, $value) {
    $this->key = $key;
    $this->value = $value;
}

public function callback($matches) {

    $matches[1] = preg_replace("%\[if @".$this->key."\]%", "", $matches[1]);
    $matches[1] = preg_replace("%\[/if]%", "", $matches[1]);

    return $matches[1];
}
}
```